# How do you power 6 servos

Tags: arduino, motor, wiring, servo

I have 6 MG996 series servomotors. A single motor can be controlled by an Arduino board using a 5V power supply.

Some specifications

- Running Current 500mA - 900mA @ 6V
- Stall Current 2.5A @ 6V

Can anyone provide some suggestion as to how I could power all 6 servomotors at once?

I don't know if I should use that really large 6V battery you typically get from the stores, and from our experience a 9V battery is too much.

Comment: What are your constraints? Size, weight, runtime, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a 6 volt power supply rated for at least 6 amps, or preferably 15 amps to allow for all motors being stalled (or started) simultaneously.

If the system has to be battery-powered, I'd use a lead-acid battery - I don't think it is practical to get this much currrent from dry cells.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. What do you think of having 4 1.5V battery connected in series?

Comment: As I said, you need a supply capable of delivering more than 6 amps if all the motors are operated at the same time.  Even "D" cells are not capable of delivering that much current for any useful time.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. We are really inexperienced when it comes to wiring stuff. If possible, could you provide exactly the kind of battery that people use out in the field (in your description)?

Comment: I would use a "Sealed Lead-Acid" or "Gel-Cell" lead acid battery rated at 12 Ampere-hours or more.  12 Ah would give you up to two hours run time between charges if the motors are running almost all the time.

Answer (score 2):

A common technology used to drive servomotors in the Radio Control community is to use LiPo batteries, and a BEC/UBEC/SBEC (Battery Eliminator Circuit). A BEC is designed to convert the battery voltage to 6V to power servos.

Battery Eliminators come in 3 basic output voltages: 5V output, 6V output or ones capable of both.

Battery Eliminators come in two types. One uses a linear voltage regulator to reduce the LiPo battery voltage down to work with servos. This wastes some of the energy as heat. That would work off 2LiPo batteries which are nominally 7.4V

The other is a switching regulator, and is able to reduce, for example 3LiPo's, 11.1V nominal to the target output voltage very efficiently with little wasted heat.

You'll need to check that a BEC provides enough current for your servos. BEC's come in a range of power handling, servos is what they are designed to drive. Remember, lots of amateurs use Radio Control models, so the technology has to work reliably.

One advantage of LiPo batteries over Lead-acid batteries is they are much lighter. Another is they come in a wide range of capability to deliver bursts of current. Finally, they come in lots of different capacities, and hence different sizes. They can also recharge quickly.

Assuming you don't intend to deliberately drive the motors into stall, a 6*900mA = 5400mAh battery would give 1 hour of continuos running, and should be able to cope with a stalled motor. Depending on what you are doing, it might power the servos for much longer than an hour.

The major downsides of LiPo batteries is they must be charged properly using a LiPo charger, and they must never ever discharge too far. You can get a 'LiPo test gizmo' which will test the batteries to show if they are okay.

You can find lots of places to buy this equipment. You may have a local Radio Control Model store, where you could have a look at the physical sizes of stuff before buying. I'm in the UK, in an average size city, and I think we have 3 or 4 RC model stores.